# i wish to make my handler function cause the program to stop executing like in the code below after prompting you to make a choice

Tags: c

```
include
include
include
void handler(int n) {
    int x;
    char ch;
    printf("Are you sure you want to Quit?\n");
    if(scanf("%c",&ch)=='y'){ return 0; }

}

int main() {

    signal(SIGTSTP, handler);   // ^Z at keyboard
    for(;;){ }

}
```

Comment: Please can you format the code so that it is readable. Please also add text to describe the problem in detail, and ask a specific question. [faq]

Answer (score 1):

```
return 0;
```

this will not terminate your program. Try to use `exit(0);` instead